# core plot: latest 1.6 version doesn't contain bitcode

Tags: ios, xcode, core-plot, ios9

I'm getting an error after upgrading to Xcode 7 and iOS 9 sdk.

```
libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a(CPTPlot.o)' does not contain bitcode. 
You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated 
library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7
```

Is there a plan for core plot to contain bitcode?  I did try disabling bitcode by going to my target > Build Options > Enable Bitcode by setting that to "No."  The app did run, but now watchOS requires bitcode, and I would guess future Apple products/OS will follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Release 2.0 should be out soon. It will be built with Xcode and include bitcode. In the meantime, you can build your own library from the code on [Github](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot). Build the "Universal Library" target to build the static library. You can use the `master` branch to get the 1.x API or the `release-2.0` branch to get the new 2.0 features and API.

Comment: I pulled CP from GITHUB a yesterday & have built the Universal version with BITCODE enabled and I get the following when I try to build my App - libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a(CPTPlot.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64. - What am I missing?

Comment: Did you download a release (2.1 came out yesterday) or are you building from source?

Comment: Thanks, I built from source, I will give 2.1 ago.

Comment: Just to help others blighted by the same problem, building the 2.1 version fixed the problem and now my App builds with ENABLE_BITCODE in the "Yes" state.